# I'm probably completely over thinking this

Tags: datetime

I am working on a calendar for our agency and want to have public access to submit events using a webform created from the webform module, and of course this event would not be published without admin signing off on it.

It doesn't appear this is a normal feature in webform/views/calendar module.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Entity forms https://www.drupal.org/project/entityform rather than webform then the user can create an entity that can be converted to your event style content type. Some form of workflow will clearly be involved. Rules may help you avoid coding.